# Dividing <div> into two parts

Tags: css, html

Not very experienced with HTML and CSS, so bear with me.

I have a large `<div>` representing the entire page, which I have divided into two parts of 30% - 70% ratio using two child  elements (to show navigation menu in the left and contents in the right ). This works fine.

Now I need to divide the left  into two parts. The bottom part should size itself to the size of its contents. The top part should take the remaining space. I have tried implementing suggestions from a number of other SO questions, but haven't been able to achieve what I need.

**Note:** If the contents of top div grow, a scrollbar should appear, instead of the top one eating up the bottom div.

CSS for the existing left and right columns is here:

```
.leftCol
{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    right: 70%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 30px;
    background: #aabbcc;
}

.rightCol
{
    position:absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    left: 30%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 30px;   
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without changing what you have so far too much, this should do it:

```
#top-left {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}

#bottom-left {
    background-color: green;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#left-col{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    right: 70%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 30px;
    background: #aabbcc; 
    height: 100%; }

#right-col {
    position:absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    left: 30%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 30px;   
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%; }
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmromer/Jhw99/). Try deleting some of the dummy text to see the top-left div expand to fill the remaining space.

I would caution against using a percentage-defined width for your sidebar, though -- as the window size is changed, the width of your navigation pane will change. That's usually not the desired behavior.

Comment: Now this is what I call a good answer. Thanks a bundle. Only one thing. If the contents of the top div grow, a scrollbar should appear. I tried adding `overflow: auto;` to the top div, but the scrollbar stretches across the entire height, and not just the top div.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it looks like `height: 100%;` for the top div makes it stretch from top to bottom of the left column. Even if scrolling is not enabled, any contents will continue flowing downward, behind the bottom div.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two more `divs` inside the left `div`

CSS:

```
    body {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .leftCol {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: auto;
        right: 70%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 30px;
        background: #aabbcc;
    }

        .leftCol .leftTop {
            background: #ff6a00;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .leftCol .leftBottom {
            background: #b6ff00;
        }

    .rightCol {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: auto;
        left: 30%;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 30px;
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="leftCol">
    <div class="leftTop">Top Left</div>
    <div class="leftBottom">Bottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom LeftBottom Left</div>
</div>
<div class="rightCol">Right Column
</div>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/T4N66/**

Answer (score 0):

How is this? http://jsfiddle.net/Z4K7J/

```
.right {
    border:1px solid orange;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
}

.left {
    border:1px solid orange;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
}

.top {
    display:table-row;
    height:100%;
}

.top .inner {
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

.bottom {
    display:table-row;
}
```

Comment: Close to what I'm trying to achieve, but only works in Chrome. In both IE and FireFox, the top <div> appears to eat up bottom <div> as its contents grow.